# Solve $(2x-3y+3)\frac{dy}{dx}=2x-2y+1$ using $z=2x-3y$ as a substitution

Tags: integration

> Use the substitution $z=2x-3y$ to solve $(2x-3y+3)\frac{dy}{dx}=2x-2y+1$ given that $y=1$ when $x=1$.

This is what I've got so far:

$$
(z+3)\frac{dy}{dx}=z+y+1
$$

But ideally I need something in the form of:

$$
\int\frac{1}{y}dy=\int\frac{z+1}{z+3}dz
$$

(The LHS and RHS are just examples - I know the calculations are incorrect). Is this the wrong approach? The answer listed is $6x^2+9y^2=12xy+18y-6x-9$ but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: do you mean $y=1$ when $x=1$?

Comment: @Adrian yeah, I've edited the question - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $z=2x-3y$ yields $dz=2dx-3dy\Rightarrow \frac{dz}{dx}=2-3\frac{dy}{dx}$ and the differential equation becomes:
$$(z+3)\cdot(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{dz}{dx})=z+y+1$$
But $y=\frac{1}{3}(2x-z)$ so
$$(z+3)\cdot(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{dz}{dx})=z+\frac{1}{3}(2x-z)+1\Leftrightarrow (z+3)(2-\frac{dz}{dx})=2z+2x+3 $$
$$(z+3)2-(z+3)\frac{dz}{dx}=2z+2x+3\Leftrightarrow -(z+3)\frac{dz}{dx}=2x-3\Leftrightarrow-(z+3)dz=(2x-3)dx$$
Direct integration yields
$$-\int(z+3)dz=\int(2x-3)dx\Leftrightarrow -\frac{(z+3)^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(2x-3)^2}{2}+c$$
Substitute back $z=2x-3y$ and your initial condition $y(1)=1$ to get the desired result.